# How to push local storage data to the server automatically when device connects to the internet in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile-application

I have recently started building apps using React Native. I would like to know how to push local storage data to the server automatically when the device connects to the internet in React Native?

Comment: Use netinfo https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo.html as explained in this article : https://medium.com/differential/handling-offline-actions-in-react-native-74949cbfabf2

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check if the device is connected with internet or not.

There are many ways to check, I'll suggest you these two:

1. [Netinfo](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo.html) :- Netinfo just reads your device's network state and tell you if your device is connected to internet via wifi or cellular network.
2. [Firebase realtime database connection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities) :-
   Firebase realtime database has offline features you can check if your app is currently connected with the firebase server, if it is connected it means the internet is working!.

If you are using Firebase in your App, i would recommend option 2.

Now after checking that your device is connected to the internet you have to write an if else condition,

For example:

```
if(internetIsOnline) {
      UploadDataToServer()
   }
 else{ 
    KeepDataInOfflineStorage()
 }
```